# howto embed RPM version number in a build product

Tags: version-control, version, rpm, rpm-spec

The RPM spec file is supposed to include a Version: keyword, e.g Version: `1.0.8`.  This version is used to name the RPM file that is generated when the RPM is built.

Is there a "canonical" way to use this to embed this bit of information into a file that either is or will make its way into the RPM.  This bit of information could then be read in by the running application and be logged/diplayed, etc.

I can think of many ways to "hack" this but is there a "right" way, an "official" way?

Comment: Isn't it just `%{version}`?

Comment: @Aaron_D_Marasco : sure, within the spec file, but what mechanism filters that into a file contained within the spec?

Comment: Oh, I use `sed` or `perl` to replace a placeholder in a file from within the `.spec`. Dunno about a more "legit" way to do it, which is why this is a comment not an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
Version:  %(sed/grep/awk commands to parse your file)
```

If you prefer to load the value to a variable, use:

```
%define myversion %(sed/grep/awk commands to parse your file)
Version:  %{myversion}
```